# Trouble passing a custom cell value to new viewController in swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, custom-cell

I have a tableview that uses custom cells. Problem is I do not know how to pass the value of a textField in my custom cell to the next view controller by using prepareForSegue. The code I am using is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StaffCell") as StaffCustomCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = StaffCustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "StaffCell")
    }

    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    cell?.staffNic?.text = object["Nic"] as String!
    cell?.staffApellido?.text = object["Apellido"] as String!

    var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "iboAzul")
    cell.staffFoto.image = initialThumbnail
    if let thumbnail = object["FotoStaff"] as? PFFile {
        cell.staffFoto.file = thumbnail
        cell.staffFoto.loadInBackground()
    }

    return cell
}


// Pass the custom cell value to the next view controller
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "segueStaffSeleccionado" {
        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController.visibleViewController as StaffDetailViewController

        // This is the code I have no idea how to write. I need to get a value from the selected customCell


    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You get the selected cell via `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`. With that indexPath you have access to the cell:

```
// Pass the custom cell value to the next view controller 
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "segueStaffSeleccionado" {
        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController.visibleViewController as StaffDetailViewController

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        // path the cell's content to your detailViewController
        detailViewController.myProperty = cell.textLabel?.text
    }
}
```

---

Another solution: If the segue is performed directly from the tableViewCell (by ctrl-dragging the segue from the cell in InterfaceBuilder) then the `sender` is the cell:

```
// Pass the custom cell value to the next view controller
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    ...

    if let cell = sender as StaffCustomCell {
        // path the cell's content to your detailViewController
        detailViewController.myProperty = cell.textLabel?.text
    }
}
```

Comment: The second solution did the trick. Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help